# Apply NGinx redirects only to main domain excluding subdomains

Tags: nginx

I have a setup of a PHP application listening in several hosts, for example:

maindomain.com
a.maindomain.com
b.maindomain.com

Some routes in maindomain.com need to be redirected. For that, I configured this redirection time ago:

```
rewrite ^/myroute/(.*)$ http://$server_name/new-myroute/$1 permanent;
```

Which makes all requests to maindomain.com/myroute/ redirect to maindomain.com/new-myroute.

The thing is that this redirects also apply to the rest of the subdomains, making a.maindomain.com/myroute redirect to maindomain.com/new-myroute.

I would like to exclude these subdomains from applying that redirection, leaving routes type a.maindomain.com/myroute untouched.

I've tried with different rewrites, like

```
rewrite ^https://maindomain.com/myroute/(.*)$ http://$server_name/new-myroute/$1 permanent;

rewrite ^maindomain.com/myroute/(.*)$ http://$server_name/new-myroute/$1 permanent;

rewrite maindomain.com/myroute/(.*)$ http://$server_name/new-myroute/$1 permanent;
```

But none of them work.

Any ideas about how to apply the redirect only to the main domain? Thanks.

Edit: the server name has a wildcard, listening to all possible subdomains that could exist:

```
server_name maindomain.com *.maindomain.com;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a separate server block or use an if condition

```
if ($host = "example.com") {
    rewrite ^/myroute/(.*)$ http://$server_name/new-myroute/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of checking the $host var. Thanks!